# SQL: How to use DECODE and COUNT functions together

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, pivot

I'm working on a homework problem, but we haven't learned about the DECODE function, only CASE. This week's unit is about using aggregate functions. Below is my homework question and what my professor wants as result-

"The following two questions are very challenging (you need to use DECODE function to complete them).

11. Create a query that will display the total number of employees and of that total
    the number who were hired in the year 1980, 1981, 1982, and 1987. Give
    appropriate column headings. (5 Points)

    ```
    Total 1980  1981  1982  1987
    ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
       14     1    10     1     2
    ```

Here is the function I typed in the server along with result. I only tried the year 1980 so I don't waste time, but I also need 1981, 1982, and 1987-

```
SELECT COUNT(ename) AS "Total",
 COUNT(DECODE(hiredate, '80', '1980'))
 FROM emp;

Total COUNT(DECODE(HIREDATE,'80','1980'))
----- -----------------------------------
   14                                   0
```

Here is the datatype for the 'hiredate' column-

```
HIREDATE
---------
17-NOV-81
01-MAY-81
09-JUN-81
02-APR-81
28-SEP-81
20-FEB-81
08-SEP-81
03-DEC-81
22-FEB-81
03-DEC-81
17-DEC-80

HIREDATE
---------
09-DEC-82
12-JAN-83
23-JAN-82
```

14 rows selected.

Thank you for anyone's help!

Comment: What is the data type of your `HIREDATE` field? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher wants you to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ename) AS "Total",
    SUM(DECODE(hire_date, 1980, 1, 0)) AS "1980",
    SUM(DECODE(hire_date, 1981, 1, 0)) AS "1981",
    SUM(DECODE(hire_date, 1982, 1, 0)) AS "1982",
    SUM(DECODE(hire_date, 1987, 1, 0)) AS "1987"
FROM emp;
```

Within each `SUM`, `DECODE()` checks the `hire_date` against the target value, and counts in only records that have the relevant date for each column.

This assumes that `hire_date` is actually a year, which seems counterintuitive. If it is a `DATE`, then you would need to extrat the year part, like so:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ename) AS "Total",
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR from hire_date), 1980, 1, 0)) AS "1980",
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR from hire_date), 1981, 1, 0)) AS "1981",
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR from hire_date), 1982, 1, 0)) AS "1982",
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR from hire_date), 1987, 1, 0)) AS "1987"
FROM emp;
```

Please note that `DECODE()` is an Oracle-specific function that is not supported by other RDBMS. A more standard way to write this is to use `CASE` blocks, with expressions like:

```
    SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR from hire_date) = 1980 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1980"
```

Comment: I am trying it out right now. Something about a "missing right parentheses". I will get back to you when done.

Comment: @strudel: my bad, I added the missing parentheses

Comment: SQL> SELECT COUNT(ename) AS "Total",
  2  SUM(DECODE(hiredate, 1980, 1, 0)) as "1980",
  3  SUM(DECODE(hiredate, 1981, 1, 0)) as "1981",
  4  SUM(DECODE(hiredate, 1982, 1, 0)) as "1982",
  5  SUM(DECODE(hiredate, 1987, 1, 0)) as "1987"
  6  FROM emp;
SUM(DECODE(hiredate, 1987, 1, 0)) as "1987"
           *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Comment: @strudel: ok so `hire_date` is a `DATE`. You should use the other expression that I put in my answer, like `SUM(DECODE(YEAR(hire_date), 1980, 1, 0)) AS "1980"` (you need to repeat that for each condition sum).

Comment: `ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier` ... `YEAR` is a MySQL function not an Oracle one.

Comment: I used your "COUNT( DECODE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hiredate ), 1980, hiredate ) ) AS "1980", and it worked. I really appreciate your time, help, and information.

Comment: Welcome @strudel! Answer by MT80 was more comprehensive than mine anyway.

Comment: Why am I getting a '0' for the year 1987?

Comment: SELECT      COUNT(ename) AS "Total",
        SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR from hiredate), 1980, 1, 0)) AS "1980",
        SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR from hiredate), 1981, 1, 0)) AS "1981",
   SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR from hiredate), 1982, 1, 0)) AS "1982",
       SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(YEAR from hiredate), 1987, 1, 0)) AS "1987"
  FROM emp

Comment: @strudel The sample data you posted has no rows for 1987 ... but it does have rows for 1983. Are you sure the question asks for 1987 and not 1983?

Comment: *Why am I getting a '0' for the year 1987* : well this simply means that no employee was hired in 1987 (this can be seen in your sample data).

Comment: Nothing for 1983. He wants 1980, 1981, 1982, 1987. I copied everything as my professor has it and the data from my SQL database.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the `hiredate` column has the data type `DATE`.

Lets do it without `DECODE` and use `PIVOT` instead:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp ( ename, hiredate ) AS
  SELECT 'A', DATE '1980-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '1981-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', DATE '1981-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', DATE '1981-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E', DATE '1981-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F', DATE '1981-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'G', DATE '1981-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'H', DATE '1981-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I', DATE '1981-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J', DATE '1981-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'K', DATE '1981-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L', DATE '1982-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'M', DATE '1987-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N', DATE '1987-02-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hiredate ) AS hireyear,
         COUNT(*) OVER () AS "Total"
  FROM   emp
)
PIVOT ( COUNT(*) FOR hireyear IN ( 1980, 1981, 1982, 1987 ) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> Total | 1980 | 1981 | 1982 | 1987
> ----: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
>    14 |    1 |   10 |    1 |    2
> ```

**Query 2**:

You can also do it with `CASE`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Total",
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN hiredate >= DATE '1980-01-01' AND hiredate < DATE '1981-01-01'
         THEN hiredate
         END
       ) AS "1980",
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN hiredate >= DATE '1981-01-01' AND hiredate < DATE '1982-01-01'
         THEN hiredate
         END
       ) AS "1981",
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN hiredate >= DATE '1982-01-01' AND hiredate < DATE '1983-01-01'
         THEN hiredate
         END
       ) AS "1982",
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN hiredate >= DATE '1987-01-01' AND hiredate < DATE '1988-01-01'
         THEN hiredate
         END
       ) AS "1987"
FROM   emp
```

**Query 3**:

Or with `DECODE`.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Total",
       COUNT( DECODE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hiredate ), 1980, 'anything here' ) ) AS "1980",
       COUNT( DECODE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hiredate ), 1981, 'anything here' ) ) AS "1981",
       COUNT( DECODE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hiredate ), 1982, 'anything here' ) ) AS "1982",
       COUNT( DECODE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hiredate ), 1987, 'anything here' ) ) AS "1987"
FROM   emp
```

*Note:* When you are counting, you count that the value passed to `COUNT` is not-`NULL` so the `DECODE` function can return any non-`NULL` value when it matches and it will get counted; conversely, so long as the value returned to `COUNT` is `NULL`, which is the default for `DECODE` when you don't supply an extra even-numbered argument, then it won't count the row.

So you could use any literal value. Like a string:

```sql
COUNT( DECODE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hiredate ), 1980, 'anything here' ) ) AS "1980"
```

or a number

```sql
COUNT( DECODE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hiredate ), 1980, 1 ) ) AS "1980"
```

or even the `hiredate` column (which if it has a year of 1980 then you know it isn't `NULL`):

```sql
COUNT( DECODE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hiredate ), 1980, hiredate ) ) AS "1980"
```

and if you want to be explicit about the return value from `DECODE` when it doesn't match then put in an extra `NULL` argument:

```sql
COUNT( DECODE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hiredate ), 1980, 42, NULL ) ) AS "1980"
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3b2e4118d29c413565fc90c8ec85b3bf)*

Comment: I even copied your corrected DECODE statement above to be safe and got "inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE". Is DECODE not good at all here to use?

Comment: @strudel What is the data type of the `hiredate` column?

Comment: This new PIVOT works great, just as expected. Do you think you can help me use DECODE so I can be safe when I submit and so I can learn it.

Comment: give me one sec and I will give you the data type for hiredate. Thank you very much.

Comment: If I use your new decode statement, where you have 'anything here', I can just delete all 4 of those?

Comment: @strudel Updated with a bit of an explanation of `COUNT` (it counts non-`NULL` values) and the `DECODE( value, value_to_match, return_value_if_matched, .... , return_value_if_none_match )` function.

Answer (score 0):

select "1981"+"1982"+"1983" Total, "1981","1982","1983"  from (select

count(case to_char(hiredate,'YYYY') when '1981' then 1 end) "1981",

count(case to_char(hiredate,'YYYY') when '1982' then 1 end) "1982",

count(case to_char(hiredate,'YYYY') when '1983' then 1 end) "1983"

from emp);

Comment: This code does not use `DECODE`.